Проблема с обновлением ссылки Яндекс
Есть такая ссылка, к которой я делаю запрос и получаю данные.
Но спустя время она перестаёт отдавать данные и возвращает словарь с одним csrftoken. Видимо есть время жизни этой ссылки, либо количество запросов, как можно обновлять эту ссылку, чтобы не ломалось получение данных.
Вообще пытаюсь получать комментарии от заведений, выводя их затем в телеграмм, вот сама страница.

чтоб обновить ссылку, нужно обновить страницу. Попробуйте из исходников страницы собрать ссылку

Предпринимаемые вами действия нарушают пользовательское соглашения Яндекс. А именно:
— пункт 4.6. Условий использования сервиса Яндекс.Карты:

«…любое копирование Данных… запрещается, за исключением случаев, прямо предусмотренных функциональными возможностями сервиса»

— пункт 5.1. Условий использования сервиса Яндекс Бизнес:

«копирование, воспроизведение, переработка, распространение, доведение до всеобщего сведения… вне рамок возможностей,
предоставляемых Сервисом… запрещается.»

Просим вас воздержаться от попыток парсинга нашей базы с отзывами и публикации их на сторонних ресурсах.

Ничего себе, настоящие?)

я же из хороших соображений это делаю, разрешите

@Danill, пользовательское соглашение есть пользовательское соглашение, с этим не поспоришь. Даже "из хороших" побуждений.
